# How to get the count of a textview in a list using espresso?

Tags: java, android, automation, android-espresso

I have a list where textView @+id/job_status is present number of times in the page. I need to find the count of it and assert it.

Scenario:

```
Filter(5)
<Item1>
<Item2>
<Item3>
```

I need to check whether the count displayed Filter("5") is same as the number of items displayed in the list.

I have tried the below method:

```
public static class RecyclerViewAssertion implements ViewAssertion {
private final int expectedCount;

public RecyclerViewAssertion(int expectedCount) {
    this.expectedCount = expectedCount;
}

@Override
public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException 
noViewFoundException) {
if (noViewFoundException != null) {
    throw noViewFoundException;
}
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
assertThat(adapter.getItemCount(), is(expectedCount));
}
}

onView (withId(android.R.id.list)).check(new 
JobsPage.RecyclerViewAssertion(5));
```

It throws me error saying : android.R.id.list matches multiple views in the hierrarchy. This id has been used in multiple places of the app. Is there any other way for this problem ?